# How can I make a github PR requesting review of entire files?

Tags: github, github-codereviews

There is [this issue](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/284) which is related, to allow commenting on parts of code OUTSIDE the change set.  I'm just wondering if anyone has clever work arounds or a process to achieve something similar, maybe simpler.

So I have a different sets of files that have been worked on and reviewed over time (in a monorepo if it is relevant).  At various points we want to have different folks review THE WHOLE SET.  So we want someone to look at all the code in each file, the whole file, just in the context of an overall security/tech debt/api design WHATEVER review.

Just as with a PR you want comments associated with lines of code.  I thought about just moving all the files under review into a new directory but that doesn't count as new content, because of git change-detection algorithms.

Does anyone have a process or approach for something similar?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I review an entire codebase on github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65961308/how-do-i-review-an-entire-codebase-on-github)

Answer (score 0):

I've found an excellent approach to reviewing the entire project files using the Code-Review plugin provided on the marketplace in VSCode.
it has cool export/ import features and useful integration with other tools such as Github/ Jira etc.
visit [the repo](https://github.com/d-koppenhagen/vscode-code-review)